# Magento 2 Fulltext search not working properly!

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, search, catalogsearch

I have products SKU like **EX-1205**, **XY-2536** or **569845**  and product Name like **TEST-2569**.

I am trying to use full-text search functionality so that a user should get the exact match for the product.

So, If user search **569845** then search is working with the exact result. But if user search **EX-1205** or **XY-2536** then showing no result.

Can anyone please help?

Comment: Can you please upload your full-text xml code.